# Setinterval() function in node js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, facebook

I have built a facebook bot but then I wanted to do an automated post request to the facebook webhook every 5 minutes. Now, firstly I am using the express framework and I would like to know if its possible to use the setinterval() in express.

```
   app.post('/webhook', function(req, res){
    var events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
    console.log(events);
    //console.log(events.length);
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            console.log("body");
            var message = event.message.text;
            var sender = event.sender.id;
            var receiver = event.recipient.id;
            var msgid = event.message.mid;
            var timestamp = event.timestamp;
            console.log(message);
            if(sender){
                console.log("Entered");
                //sendbuttonlink(sender);
            }

        }
    }

    res.status(200).end();

});
```

I am using ngrok for now. So, I am using nrgok to tunnel my request to the backend.

I tried to use the setinterval() without the express framework but it keeps giving me a 404. But when I do a http post on that link from POSTMAN, I am getting a response. What could be the issue?

```
var requestLoop = setInterval(function(){
  request({
      url: "https:/*****.ngrok.io/webhook",
      method: "POST",
      timeout: 10000,
      followRedirect: true,
      maxRedirects: 10
  },function(error, response, body){
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
          console.log('sucess!');
      }else{
          console.log('error' + response.statusCode);
      }
  });
}, 200);
```

Comment: Make sure you are making request to the correct url from node. Everything else looks fine. And of course you can use setInterval